# building open-daylight project

Tags: maven, apache-karaf, opendaylight

I am trying the hello world example using the following mvn build.

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release/ -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.0-Carbon

I am still confused when to use other **DarchetypeGroupId**   (eg. **org.opendaylight.l2switch**) or other **DarchetypeArtifactId** (eg. md-sal-app-simple).

I can see some jar files loaded into my project, how exactly should I specify what jar file I need to add?

I also tried to import the "**PacketProcessingListener**"  in my HelloWorldImpl.java, to test how I can extract/analyze some packet info (e. IP and port numbers). but the package was not there?

I believe I need to add some artifacts in one of the pom.xml files, but I am totally lost :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to include needed bundles, add the following to pom.xml of the implementation folder

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.model</groupId>
    <artifactId>model-flow-service</artifactId>
      <version>*.*.*</version>
</dependency>
```